# spliting a txt file with text in several parts

Tags: bash, parsing, text, text-parsing

I have a .txt file:

```
level5:tafekf
level5:tafekg
level5:tafekh
level5:tafeki
level5:tafekj
level5:tafekk
level5:tafekl
level5:tafekm
level5:tafekn
level5:tafeko
level5:tafekp
level5:tafekq
level5:tafekr
level5:tafeks
level5:tafekt
level5:tafeku
level5:tafekv
level5:tafekw
level5:tafekx
level5:tafeky
level5:tafekz
level5:tafela
level5:tafelb
level5:tafelc
level5:tafeld
level5:tafele
level5:tafelf
level5:tafeku
level5:tafekv
level5:tafekw
level5:tafekv
level5:tafekw
```

And I would like using a command in linux terminal to split in in for example 10 times.
So I would expect to have 10 .txt files as output with

1.txt

```
    level5:tafekf
    level5:tafekg
    level5:tafekh
```

2.txt

```
    level5:tafeki
    level5:tafekj
    level5:tafekk
```

3.txt

```
    level5:tafekl
    level5:tafekm
    level5:tafekn
```

4.txt

```
    level5:tafeko
    level5:tafekp
    level5:tafekq
```

5.txt

```
    level5:tafekr
    level5:tafeks
    level5:tafekt
```

6.txt

```
    level5:tafeku
    level5:tafekv
    level5:tafekw
```

7.txt

```
    level5:tafekx
    level5:tafeky
    level5:tafekz
```

8.txt

```
    level5:tafela
    level5:tafelb
    level5:tafelc
```

9.txt

```
    level5:tafeld
    level5:tafele
    level5:tafelf
```

10.txt

```
    level5:tafeku
    level5:tafekv
    level5:tafekw
    level5:tafeih
    level5:tafeii
```

Thank you.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus I know that I need t use perl. But have no idea the commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split` command from GNU coreutils:

```
split -n l/10 --numeric-suffixes=1 --additional-suffix=.txt input.file
```

I hope the output names are good enough for you. They start at `x01.txt` followed by `x02.txt` and so on. For more information invoke `info split`.

---

The above command works on GNU systems, like Linux. Other systems may ship with a version of split as well but it isn't compatible with the GNU version. For a portable version I would use awk like this:

*split.awk*

```
{
    a[NR]=$0
    c++ 
}

END {
    lines_per_split = int(c/num_splits)
    f=1 
    for(i=1;i<=c;i++) {
        print a[i] >> f".txt"
        if(i%lines_per_split==0 && c-i >= lines_per_split) {
            close(f".txt")
            f++
        }
    }   
}
```

Call it like this:

```
awk -vnum_splits=10 -f split.awk input.txt
```

Comment: I tried but I have this error: split: illegal option -- n
usage: split [-a sufflen] [-b byte_count] [-l line_count] [-p pattern]
             [file [prefix]]

Comment: Use Linux! ;) .. However, since also MacOX has a, less capable, split program, it should be good enough. Check man split on your system

Comment: I have access to an ubuntu server and it worked on ubuntu. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. It's late here. I can add an `awk` version which should work on both Mac and Linux tomorrow.

Comment: can you add awk version? It would be better for my solution. Thank you